# How to convert Redisgraph to networkx graph to be used in Node2vec algorithm?

Tags: graph, redis, networkx, redisgraph

I have created a Redisgraph and I am able to execute queries on it using Redisinsight and redis-cli. Now, I want to create graph-embeddings using Node2vec. But, I am not able to pass redisgraph in Node2vec(). It is showing error that the passed graph is of 'dict' type. All the Node2vec tutorials that I found use Networkx graph to create graph embeddings. Is there any way to use Node2vec on redis-graph, or some way to convert redis-graph to networkx graph ?

Answer (score 2):

I assume we'll be able to provide a [networkx](https://github.com/networkx/networkx) integration, I'm not familiar with networkx, there's an [open issue](https://github.com/RedisGraph/redisgraph-py/issues/4) on the matter, It would be wonderful if such an integration would be contributed by the open source community, I'll be glad to provide assistance.

Comment: Okay. So I think I need to create the graph again in Networkx. Thanks for your prompt reply.